# Databinding XML in C# (WP8)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, windows-phone-8

I'm not sure if this is correct, but trying to learn MVVM, how it works, etc.

Currently, the example used to load the data is:

```
  this.SavedItems.Add(new SavedBoard() { ID= "1098", UserDescription = "Test" });
```

I want to parse XML and load data from there.

This is the c# code I've been trying but doesn't seem to work:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("savedstops.xml");
        var data = from query in doc.Descendants("Stops")
                   select new SavedBoard
                       {
                           ID = query.Element("ID").Value,
                           UserDescription = query.Element("UserDescription").Value
                       };

        this.SavedItems.Add(data);
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<Stops>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1022</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
    <Stop>
        <ID>1053</ID>
        <UserDescription>Test1045</UserDescription>
    </Stop>
</Stops>
```

Where am I going wrong? I also get an error Error "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?"

Though I'm thinking the error isn't the reason it's not working, but rather the code logic itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `doc.Descendants("Stop")` (or `doc.Root.Elements("Stop")`) instead of `Stops`, and include the `System.Linq` namespace with adding: `using System.Linq;` top of your code.

Comment: The namespaces is what got me! Thanks!